# OpenGL ES Shader to outline 2D images

Tags: opengl-es, shader

I'm working on an 2D iOS game using OpenGL 2.0 and I'm wondering if it's possible to write a shader that will outline images with a glow.  All the images are 2D sprites.  The shader examples I've seen for outlining are for 3D objects, so I'm not sure if it possible for 2D images.

Comment: so the glow you want to add is like a drop shadow?

Comment: More of a stroke around the image that would have soft edges.

Answer (score 7):

Would you accept an edge detection filter (such as Sobel), producing an image like that shown in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator), followed by a Gaussian blur on the results of that to soften the edges and give it more of a glow, then composite that image onto your scene?

In practice you could probably just reuse the 3d outlining shaders you've seen — although you could in theory inspect depth quantities (with some extended effort in ES), every one I've ever seen was just a 2d effect on the rendered image.

EDIT: on further consideration, the Laplacian may be a little easier to apply than the Sobel because it can be done as a simple convolution shaders (as described in places [like this](http://buza.mitplw.com/blog/?p=159)). Though to be safe on mobile you possibly want to stick to 3x3 kernels at most and write a different shader for each effect rather than doing it with data. So e.g. a rough Gaussian blur, written out at length:

```
void main()
{
    mediump vec4 total = vec4(0.0);
    mediump vec4 grabPixel;

    total +=        texture2D(tex2D, texCoordVarying + vec2(-1.0 / width, -1.0 / height));
    total +=        texture2D(tex2D, texCoordVarying + vec2(1.0 / width, -1.0 / height));
    total +=        texture2D(tex2D, texCoordVarying + vec2(1.0 / width, 1.0 / height));
    total +=        texture2D(tex2D, texCoordVarying + vec2(-1.0 / width, 1.0 / height));

    grabPixel =     texture2D(tex2D, texCoordVarying + vec2(0.0, -1.0 / height));
    total += grabPixel * 2.0;

    grabPixel =     texture2D(tex2D, texCoordVarying + vec2(0.0, 1.0 / height));
    total += grabPixel * 2.0;

    grabPixel =     texture2D(tex2D, texCoordVarying + vec2(-1.0 / width, 0.0));
    total += grabPixel * 2.0;

    grabPixel =     texture2D(tex2D, texCoordVarying + vec2(1.0 / width, 0.0));
    total += grabPixel * 2.0;

    grabPixel = texture2D(tex2D, texCoordVarying);
    total += grabPixel * 4.0;

    total *= 1.0 / 16.0;

    gl_FragColor = total;
}
```

And a Laplacian edge detect ends up looking similar but with different constants.

As an optimisation, you should work out your relative sampling points in the vertex shader rather than in the fragment shader as far as possible given the limit on varyings, as doing so will avoid dependent texture reads.

Comment: Maybe I'm not looking at the right 3D ones, but the ones I've seen seem to operate on the light source to some degree, which I don't have given it's 2D.  I've very new to shaders, so I'm probably overlooking the obvious here.

Comment: A lot of the post-Jet Set Radio cell shaders use the camera position to detect edges by defining an edge to be the join between a forward facing edge and a backward facing edge. You'll obviously not be able to use one of those. But approaches like Sobel and the Laplacian look for discontinuities in colour in a 2d image to spot edges, so are entirely appropriate. It's probably smart to read up on convolution filters, if you haven't yet, then investigate the Laplacian and Gaussian blur. I've added some hastily assembled sample code for the latter.